# How to get the ip to use with allow/deny in my htaccess (with php)

Tags: php, .htaccess, ip, same-origin-policy

How do I get the IP, with PHP, that I have to use for my htaccess to allow specific domains access to my content?

I used `gethostbyname($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])` to get the ip, but that seems not to be the right one?
Or maybe something is wrong with my .htaccess file?

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from All
Allow from 77.111.240.115
```

*I now see that there are a lot websites hosted on this IP, is there a way to get this working?*

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the visitor's IP `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`, and not for the server's IP? Also, the *.htaccess* syntax you posted is for apache2.2. Please update the question explaining clearly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @simlev no I want to communicate from 1 site to another, but restrict access form everywhere else.

Comment: In that case, you should retrieve the visitor's IP on the second server while visiting from the first, and then filter by that IP on the second server.

Comment: why not just allow server ip?

Comment: They not necessarily the same.

Comment: `HTTP_HOST` is the host name from the request, so if someone else requests data from your site, that will be _your_ site’s domain name. (resp. one of them, in case you had domain aliases or something like that.)

Comment: _“I want to communicate from 1 site to another, but restrict access form everywhere else”_ - and “communicate” entails what, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You did mentioned that you are looking to just allow specific domains to access your website.

Try this in your .htaccess and it won't require you to deal with IPs etc.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} 
!^http(s)?://(www\.)?yoursite.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} 
!^http(s)?://(www\.)?othersite.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|html|php)$ - [F]
```

The above thing will allow access to your own website and that other website to files like jpg gif html etc.

If you want you can add other file extensions in it and if you want you can add other websites in it.